# "Transitivity works on simple graphs only" InternalError in igraph

Tags: python, igraph

I'm analysing a big graph - 30M nodes and 350M+ edges - using the python interface of igraph. I can load the edges without any issue but executing a function like *transitivity_local_undirected* to compute the clustering coefficient of each node returns the error "Transitivity works on simple graphs only, Invalid value".

I can't find anything online - any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simple graph is a graph with no loops or multiple edges -- it sounds like the computer thinks your graph is non-simple for some reason.

Are you sure your nodes have no loops or multiple edges between them?